# Automation Anywhere. Using variables to select window in object cloning command

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I'm using Object cloning command with internet explorer. In the object cloning command, I select the window from the drop down list and clone my object. If I run the task everything works fine. Then I changed the window name with a variable. This variable has the exact same value as the name selected from the drop down list.

When I run the task with the variable, it restores the screen (not full screen). Although the task works fine most of the time, some properties of the webpage change when the screen is not maxed. I tried using maximize window but the next object cloning command will restore the window again.

Has anyone had this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got to fix the problem. The problem was the variable I was using. The first time you use a new variable to select a window in object cloning, it will prompt a list of open windows so that you refer your variable to it. It looks like the variable memorizes the size of the windows the first time you use it. At first I didn't think this was the problem because I deleted and recreated the same variable, and also changed it's name. Only when I created a complete different variable, use it for object cloning and selected "none of the above" from the list window, then it would work with out restoring the screen. I'm not 100% sure if this is the reason, but this fixed the problem for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Trust that you are well.

I have read your query and try to replicate similar stuff in my machine.

I have not encountered this issue when i ran code keeping window name in variable. But i have got one way to to make it work.

The secrete is use Keystroke to make it maximize IE  as follows :

-"**[ALT DOWN] [ALT UP]x**" --> Alt key + One space + x alphabet - key combination ,

try this your code and let me know if you are able to solve this.

Regards,

NoSpaceForLove

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I solved the problem a few days ago and forgot to publish the answer.